# How can I mask only a part of the image in python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

When I mask the image in opencv, lots of things inside image appears in white color, but I only want a particular region of the image in white color.
These are the co-ordinates of that region :
540:740,340:440
How can I mask only this region from the entire image?.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a methode. I used this methode for a ai that only need a part of a picture. So "vertices" has to be a np array which includes the coords

```
def roi(img, vertices):
    mask = np.zeros_like(img)
    cv2.fillPoly(mask, vertices, 255)
    masked = cv2.bitwise_and(img, mask)
    return masked
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set that part of the matrix to your desired color.

```
import numpy as np
mask = 255 * np.ones(((740-540),(440-340),3),dtype=int)
image[540:740,340:440,:] = mask
```

Comment: I am using int, but it could be that your image is using float values. Then change the mask line accordingly.